# How can I properly align sections in my list?

Tags: lists

I am having trouble aligning sections/subsections with their corresponding section/subsection.  Please see the following example:

[image]

Here is all of the code entered so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

\section{Operational rules for constructing an upper line with a basic step motion}

\subsection{The basic step motion}

\begin{enumerate}

 \item The final pitch in the basic step motion must be a tonic.
 
 \item The first pitch in the basic step motion must be a tonic triad member a third, a fifth, or an octave above the final pitch.
 
 \item These two pitches must be joined by inserting the pitches of intervening diatonic degrees to form a descending step motion.
 
\subsection{Beginning of Two-Voice Setting}
 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I have seen some questions related to margins and shifting text in terms of inches, but I am curious to see if there's a simpler approach that I might be missing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the second subsection (1.2) inside the enumerate environment. Change like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

\section{Operational rules for constructing an upper line with a basic step motion}

\subsection{The basic step motion}

\begin{enumerate}

 \item The final pitch in the basic step motion must be a tonic.
 
 \item The first pitch in the basic step motion must be a tonic triad member a third, a fifth, or an octave above the final pitch.
 
 \item These two pitches must be joined by inserting the pitches of intervening diatonic degrees to form a descending step motion.

\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Beginning of Two-Voice Setting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Premise:** I suspect this solution, although it appears to work, is a bit convoluted. Maybe some guru can find an elegant one.

I don't understand why to put a `\subsection` inside an `enumerate`, as @Fran- pointed out. However the `\subsection` is shifted to the right by `\leftmargin`. We then have to modify the indentation of the `\subsection` from `\z@` to `-\leftmargin`, but only if the command is given inside a list. This can be easily done through `etoolbox`:

```
\pretocmd{\list}{\patchcmd{\subsection}{\z@}{-\leftmargin}{}{}}{}{}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\list}{\patchcmd{\subsection}{\z@}{-\leftmargin}{}{}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\list}{\patchcmd{\subsubsection}{\z@}{-\leftmargin}{}{}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Operational rules for constructing an upper line with a basic step motion}

\subsection{The basic step motion}

\begin{enumerate}

 \item The final pitch in the basic step motion must be a tonic.
 
 \item The first pitch in the basic step motion must be a tonic triad member a third, a fifth, or an octave above the final pitch.
 
 \item These two pitches must be joined by inserting the pitches of intervening diatonic degrees to form a descending step motion.

\subsection{Teginning of Two-Voice Setting}
\subsection*{A non-numbered subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\item Another item

\subsection*{A non-numbered section}
 
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Teginning of Two-Voice Setting}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\subsection*{Another non-numbered subsection}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you!  Fran's answer seemed to be more straightforward, so that's the one I went with.  Thank you for the feedback though--I appreciate it.